# Complicated sql date logic: How can I schedule my reports?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, logic

I have a table that looks something like this (simplified):

```
*ScheduledReports*
ReportID  
StartDate  
Frequency  
Interval (1=months, 2=days)
```

So if I would want to run a report every 3 days, frequency would be 3 and interval would be 2.

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that we can run once a day, that will run all reports from the table that are scheduled for today (or should have been run since the last time we ran the stored procedure).

The stored procedure also has access to the lastRunTime (the last time this stored procedure was run).

This is what my query looks like so far:

```
-- get monthly reports that should be run
SELECT reportID
FROM ScheduledReports
WHERE intervalType = 1 AND
    dateadd(m,  (
           frequency * ceiling((
              --sql server calculates datediff of months based on the actual int of the month
              --not if it's a true month later, so the following is necessary to check for
              --a dayOfMonth difference
              CASE
                  WHEN startDate > @lastRunTime
                         THEN 0
                  WHEN day(startDate) > day(@lastRunTime)
                         THEN datediff(m, startDate, @lastRunTime) - 1
                  ELSE datediff(m, startDate, @lastRunTime)
                  END
              ) / (frequency*1.0))
           ), startDate) BETWEEN @lastRunTime AND getDate()

UNION ALL

-- get weekly reports that should be run 
SELECT reportID
FROM ScheduledReports
WHERE intervalType = 2 AND
    dateadd(d, (
           frequency * ceiling((
              CASE
                  WHEN startDate > @lastRunTime
                         THEN 0
                  ELSE datediff(d, startDate, @lastRunTime)
                  END
              ) / (frequency*1.0)
           )), startDate) BETWEEN @lastRunTime AND getDate()
```

There is something off with the logic though. What is wrong with my logic? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What if the last time the report was run was more than one day ago?

Comment: @mark bannister - we want to send it once if it should've been sent any time between the last time it was run and today

Comment: Would a solution that had you create another table be acceptable? Or are you constrained to only work with what you currently have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to fix the bug - we were supposed to be adding 1 in the case, not subtracting, because we want to get the next run date, not the previous. Changed the month case to:

```
 CASE
        WHEN startDate > @lastRunTime
              THEN 0
        WHEN day(startDate) > day(@lastRunTime)
              THEN datediff(m, startDate, @lastRunTime)
        ELSE datediff(m, startDate, @lastRunTime) + 1
 END
```

and the day case to:

```
CASE
     WHEN startDate > @lastRunTime
        THEN 0
     ELSE datediff(d, startDate, @lastRunTime) + 1
END
```

And now it is working perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

> The stored procedure also has access to the lastRunTime (the last time this stored procedure was run).

Don't you need to know the last time each report was produced?  And not the last time this sproc was run?  Each time you run the sproc, each report may or may not be produced.  In order to know if the interval for each report has passed for each report (3 days, 1 month, etc) you need to know when THAT report was last produced.

What if you add a LastReportRun date column to your table.  Then don't test todays date against @lastRunTime, but rather against LastReportRun.

```
Report Run Today; Today = 2012/04/15

ID  StartDate   Freqcy  Interval  LastReportRun
--  ----------  ------  --------  ----------------  
1    2000/01/01  1      Days      2012/04/14         1 day ago;    print it
2    2000/01/01  14     Days      2012/04/09         6 days ago;   don`t print it
3    2000/01/01  3      Months    2012/01/13         > 3 mos ago;  print it
4    2000/01/01  3      Months    2012/01/17         < 3 mos ago;  don`t print it
```

Comment: I want it to run based off of the start date. So if the start date is 12/1/2011, and the frequency and interval is every month, then I want it to run on 1/1/2012, 2/1/2012, etc. If I run the procedure on 2/2/2012, and the last run date is 1/31/2012, I should be able to figure out that I need to run it today to make up for missing 2/1/2012...